# Simple front end for scientific code

Tags: python, c++, frontend

Currently I have a program where I pass some parameters and files to the main executable through the command line

e.g. Ill run a simulation through

> ./exe param1 param2 param3 .. etc

However to make this code more user friendly, I would like to have a system where you can load parameter files, and run a simulation on them, which seems to be a common with scientific code

Now I would like to move to a system where I can run something like

> ./exe simulation.params

I would think to create a class of all my parameters

```
class Parameter {
    //objects that are parameters 
}
```

and then pass this around inside my main program, with something like a map from the variables in the file to the variables in the simulation. The main program just loops over each line in the input file, reading info and initialising this class.

Also it would be nice to either run the program in an interactive shell or just pass the file. Maybe just check if given a file (with some necessary checks) then runs, or just brings up an interactive session,

roughly

```
int main()
{
   if(argc== 1)
   {
    // run simulation on file
   }
   else
   {
     //bring up some menu 
   }

}
```

Are these good practice? Most of the parameters are numbers, is there a recommended format? Are there any other useful libraries that help implement things like this? Would it be better to create the front end in something like python?

Comment: This isn't the right place to come with questions like this (unfortunately I don't know where is...).  If you come with "I'm doing X and using approach Y but ran into trouble with Z" then you'll get much better responses.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to introduce parameter names, one of which could be file name with settings. Also it would be better if you would not stick to only file-based or arg-based settings, but will allow file settings to be overridden by command line arguments. Basically you initialization would look like this:

- Process command line arguments
- Load configuration from file if present
- Apply configuration values from command line

There is a nice function getopt, defined in POSIX standard (which means - available in standard library). GNU provides extension called getopt_long, which allows you to have also "long" options like "--param". More information on getopt/getopt_long with examples available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)